# How to improve PostgreSQL intersect speed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, intersect

I have created the following table in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id serial, c1 int, c2 int)
```

The following query takes 0.9 ms to complete:

```
select id from mytable where c1=555 and c2=444;
```

The following query takes 6.5 ms to complete:

```
select id from mytable where c1=555 intersect select id from mytable where c2=444;
```

The query plan for the first query is:

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=46.90..54.84 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.623..0.626 rows=2 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((c2 = 444) AND (c1 = 555))
   Heap Blocks: exact=2
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=46.90..46.90 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.609..0.610 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i2  (cost=0.00..23.31 rows=1985 width=0) (actual time=0.267..0.267 rows=1978 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (c2 = 444)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i1  (cost=0.00..23.33 rows=1987 width=0) (actual time=0.258..0.258 rows=1988 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (c1 = 555)
```

and for the second plan is:

```
HashSetOp Intersect  (cost=23.81..10244.16 rows=1985 width=8) (actual time=6.784..6.804 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=23.81..10234.23 rows=3972 width=8) (actual time=0.543..6.093 rows=3966 loops=1)
         ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=23.81..5106.08 rows=1985 width=8) (actual time=0.542..2.928 rows=1978 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=23.81..5086.23 rows=1985 width=4) (actual time=0.540..2.636 rows=1978 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (c2 = 444)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=1810
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i2  (cost=0.00..23.31 rows=1985 width=0) (actual time=0.331..0.331 rows=1978 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (c2 = 444)
         ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=23.83..5108.29 rows=1987 width=8) (actual time=0.537..2.790 rows=1988 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable mytable_1  (cost=23.83..5088.42 rows=1987 width=4) (actual time=0.536..2.495 rows=1988 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (c1 = 555)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=1812
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i1  (cost=0.00..23.33 rows=1987 width=0) (actual time=0.340..0.340 rows=1988 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (c1 = 555)
```

The difference in speed seems to be due to **BitmapAnd** being used in the first query execution. Is there anyway to make postgres do a similar execution for the second query as well ?

Comment: shouldn't there be some indexes, especially a combined for the first and a rule of thumb don't use functions that you don't need

Comment: I forgot to mention this. I have created the following two indexes:

    CREATE INDEX i1 ON mytable (c1)

    CREATE INDEX i2 ON mytable (c2)

I am trying to understand some of these concepts. So, I didn't create a compound index on (c1, c2).

Comment: An INTERSECT takes both subqueries and compare every row if  there is a match. Which will take time by nature of it

Comment: Both queries return the same result. Both are performing the equivalent of an intersect. There is no 'union' happening here. 'union' would have happened if I had used the query with "c1=555 or c2=444"

Comment: yes they give the same result and no they don't do the same else they would have the same execution plan

Comment: What is the real question here?  You already know how to write the query in a more natural and also more performant way, so just do that rather than using a gratuitously convoluted and horrible method, which also performs worse.

Comment: I thought I had made my question clear. Anyway, I'll repeat it here - the question is how to make the intersect perform as well as the other query. I know that the other query performs better but I have to use this query - it is not a choice I can make. This is a simplified example I have given above to illustrate the difference in query times. The actual problem is with a table used for implementing an entity-attribute-value pattern where there are no multiple columns for using the 'and' type query. You can imagine just 3 columns for EAV. Intersect is all I can do there.

Comment: 0.9 ms and 6.5 ms are not different enough. Please use non-trivail sample data when tuning queries. (and I don't think that EAV causes the need for INTERSECT)

Comment: Your basic problem:  Entity-Attribute-Value = design that will never perform well.

Comment: @wildplasser , I am using the following type of query: `select entity_id from mytable where attr='name' and value='Rahul' intersect select entity_id from mytable where attr='location' and 'value'='India'` to find all users with name 'Rahul' and location 'India'.

Comment: @Belayer , I think the same problem will be there if I normalize the DB. When there are multi-valued attributes, I can create separate tables `create table attr1 (id int, value int, foreign key id references entity(id))` and `create table attr2 (id int, value int, foreign key id references entity(id))`. The query would still be something like `select id from attr1 where value='v1' intersect select id from attr2 where value='v2'` . There is no problem with single valued attributes - I can put all of them in same table and do the 'good' query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stepping onto an unpinned page which is already in shared buffers is quite slow.  Not compared to reading that page from disk of course, but compared to anything else you do. Several atomic operations are required to make sure concurrent processes don't corrupt each other while they do this, and it will almost surely also involve CPU cache misses.  Your HashSetOp needs to do this a lot more than the BitmapAnd does (around 1800 times more, based on your query plan numbers--but that is only counting table pages).  The BitmapAnd intersects ctids read from the index in its local memory and then only hits the table for those surviving the intersect, while your HashSetOp needs to hit the table before it can do the intersect because it is intersecting SQL fields, not ctids.

You can improve the bad query by getting it to use index-only scans.  If the query doesn't need to hit the table at all because it can find the SQL field in the index, then it needs to visit far fewer pages (the index pages have many relevant tuples crammed into each page)

If I build indexes on `(c1, id)` and `(c2, id)`, so I got each subquery to use index-only scans, the resulting HashSetOp plan is 3 to 4 times faster than the original HashSetOp plan without those indexes, while still being
2 to 3 times slower than the BitmapAnd.  This is on a freshly VACUUMed table, so that all pages are marked all-visible.

Comment: This did speed up the query quite a bit. When I tried it now with those indexes I am getting 0.862 ms for the first query and 1.455 ms for the second. BTW, there are 2 million rows in the table. Your explanation cleared up a lot of my doubts. Thank you.